# Markdown Editor Updating State Issue React & Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

```js
"use client";

import { useState, useLayoutEffect } from "react";
import { useParams } from "next/navigation";
import React from "react";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
const SimpleMDE = dynamic(() => import("react-simplemde-editor"), { ssr: false });
import "easymde/dist/easymde.min.css";

export default function NewResource() {
  const { id } = useParams();

  const [markdownDescription, setMarkdownDescription] = useState("");
  const [markdownTOS, setMarkdownTOS] = useState("");
  const [markdownPP, setMarkdownPP] = useState("");



  async function saveResource() {
    console.log(markdownDescription); // logs undefined
  }


  return (
    <div>

       <SimpleMDE key={markdownDescription} value={markdownDescription} onChange={({ text }) => setMarkdownDescription(text)} />
                  
  );
}
```

As you can see when text is inputted in the Markdown editor, it is meant to update markdownDescription. However when I log it in the async function (it's called through a button click later on), it logs undefined.

Comment: You can simply write `onChange={setMarkdownDescription}` it will automatically pass the value.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the documentation of the SImpleMDE library, you will see the correct way to grap the value from onChange

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-simplemde-editor#controlled-usage

Try to change your `onChange` handler to this

```
 onChange={(value) => setMarkdownDescription(value)}
```

Comment: I tried, it logs correctly everywhere in my code besides the async function

Comment: Please show how you call `saveResourses` function

Comment: <button
            type="submit"
            onClick={saveResource}
            className="rounded-md bg-blue-600 px-3 py-2 text-sm font-semibold text-white shadow-sm hover:bg-blue-600 focus-visible:outline focus-visible:outline-2 focus-visible:outline-offset-2 focus-visible:outline-blue-600"
          >
            Save
          </button>

Comment: From what i see I cant figure out your problem but you may try using refs to access in a hacky way like this 
```const [markdownDescription, setMarkdownDescription] = useState('');
  const markdownDescriptionRef = useRef(markdownDescription);

  useEffect(() => {
    markdownDescriptionRef.current = markdownDescription;
  }, [markdownDescription]);

  async function saveResource() {
    console.log(markdownDescriptionRef.current); // should log the current markdownDescription
  }```